# I2C Reads Returning Zero (RPi 4, SenseHat, Pi4J)

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, i2c, raspberry-pi4

I am working on a project with a Raspberry Pi 4 and Sense Hat. I am trying to get the temperature, humidity, and barometric pressure readings from the Hat in Java. I don't want to use Python or other language here, as I will be integrating this into a Spring Boot project later on.

Whenever I read from the I2C addresses for temperature / pressure / humidity, I get a return value of 0.

According to https://pinout.xyz/pinout/sense_hat, the I2C addresses are as follows:

Pressure / Temp: 0x5c
Humidity / Temp: 0x5f

I am using Pi4j, and the code I am using is a modified version of their [I2C example](https://pi4j.com/documentation/io-examples/i2c/):

```
package com.example;

import com.pi4j.Pi4J;
import com.pi4j.context.Context;
import com.pi4j.io.i2c.I2C;
import com.pi4j.io.i2c.I2CConfig;
import com.pi4j.io.i2c.I2CProvider;

public class App 
{

    static final int tempAddress = 0x5c;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        Context pi4j = Pi4J.newAutoContext();
        I2CProvider i2CProvider = pi4j.provider("linuxfs-i2c");
        I2CConfig i2cConfig = I2C.newConfigBuilder(pi4j).id("TEMP").bus(1).device(tempAddress).build();
        try (I2C temp = i2CProvider.create(i2cConfig)) {

            byte temperature = (byte) temp.readRegister(tempAddress);
            
            System.out.println(temperature);
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

The code compiles and runs, but I always get 0 printed to the console. I have tried both of the above addresses and get the same result. Interestingly, if I use address 0x6a (which should be the magnetometer) I get an output of -95.

When I run i2cdetect in the terminal, I get the following:

```
chris@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1c -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 39 -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- 46 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5c -- -- 5f 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 6a -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         
chris@raspberrypi:~ $
```

So it looks like the registers I am using are correct, but there's something wrong with my implementation.

I did find [someone facing the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76368816/how-to-read-from-i2c-on-rpi-using-java-pi4j), but the resolution is unclear. It seems like in that user's case the device may need something to be written before it is read (?) but I can find nothing for the Sense Hat that documents the i2c in that sort of detail. The official documentation mostly just shows usage with Python functions, not directly reading from the i2c bus.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this some more the day after my post, and figured out my issues.

Firstly, I was incorrect about the way the i2c addressing works. 0x5c is the address of the chip that reads pressure / temp, but that is the address for the entire chip. The temperature readings are found by reading two specific registers in the chip, and then doing some additional operations on them. The corrected code would be similar to the following:

```
/**
* I2C registers where data is read from the chips
*/
static final int LPS25H_TEMP_OUT_H_REGISTER = 0x2c;
static final int LPS25H_TEMP_OUT_L_REGISTER = 0x2b;

public static double getTempFromPressure(){
        double temperature = 0;

        I2C tempI2C = getI2C("TEMPFROMPRESSURE", LPS25H_ADDRESS);
        
        try  {

            if(!initializeLPS25H(tempI2C)){
                //Add proper exception-handling here later
                System.out.println("Error initializing LPS25H");
            }

            //Get the temperature readings from the registers and store them as Strings
            String tempStringHigh = Integer.toBinaryString(tempI2C.readRegister(LPS25H_TEMP_OUT_H_REGISTER));
            String tempStringLow = Integer.toBinaryString(tempI2C.readRegister(LPS25H_TEMP_OUT_L_REGISTER));
            
            //The readings from the registers represent 8 bit values. Add zeroes to the left hand side until the values are 8 bits
            tempStringHigh = fillEightBit(tempStringHigh);
            tempStringLow = fillEightBit(tempStringLow);

            //Concatenate the two strings to get the 16 bit value for the temperature
            String tempString = tempStringHigh + tempStringLow;

            double cycles;

            /**
             * If the leading bit is a zero, convert from twos-complement. 
             * 
             * Otherwise simply convert to an integer
             * 
             * (Cycles is the nomenclature in LPS25H docs, so I am keeping it consistent here)
             */
            if(tempString.charAt(0) == '1'){
                cycles = fromTwosComplement(tempString);
            }else{
                cycles = Integer.parseInt(tempString, 2); 
            }

            //Temperature offset is cycles/480, relative to a base number of 42.5 degrees Celsius
            temperature = 42.5 + (cycles/480);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        

        return temperature;
    }
```

In addition, I found that some registers on the chip need to be manually set by writing certain values. So the following is used to initiate the chip once before reading:

```
public static boolean initializeLPS25H(I2C tempI2C){
            try{
                //Set CTRL_REG1. Enable output, set data rate to 25Hz, don't update output registers until MSB and LSB update
                tempI2C.writeRegister(0x20, 0xc4); 
                //Set RES_CONF. Set temp internal avereage to 16, pressure internal average to 32
                tempI2C.writeRegister(0x10, 0x05);
                //Set FIFO_CTRL. Set FIFO to generate a running average filtered pressure
                tempI2C.writeRegister(0x2E, 0xc0);
                //Set CTRL_REG4. Unclear what this does in RTIMU, doing it here until I can test.
                tempI2C.writeRegister(0x23, 0x40);

                return true;
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
                return false;
            }


    }
```

As mentioned above, credit for this goes to the creators of RTIMU. I learned a lot of the above from reading the chip documentation, but setting those initial values was something I learned by reading through the RTIMU code available on Github.

I'll be open-sourcing all the above code once I've added all the different Pi HAT functions. I'm thinking of making this into a simple library once it's done, so others can easily import it later.